# Two User Git and Two Different Project in the Same Server

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have two accounts Github (UserA and UserB)

I have Two project (projectA e ProjectB)

Both(private)

I have three Server (Server A, ServerB, Local)

In Server A I have The ProjectA and i can do Push merge commit etc...

```
root@UserA:~/.ssh# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi UserA! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

In Server B I have The ProjectB and i can do Push merge commit etc...

```
root@UserB:~/.ssh# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi UserB! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

In Local Server I want both Repository and Both User and both project. For Now i have only UserA (ssh key)

i try to copy

```
id_rsa.github.projectB 
id_rsa.github.projectB.pub
```

and i have

project A

```
id_rsa.github 
id_rsa.github.pub
```

project B

```
id_rsa.github.projectB 
id_rsa.github.projectB.pub
```

to /root/.ssh in Local Server And Create this file

```
# account per UserA
Host github.com-UserA
    HostName github.com
    User UserA
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# account for the UserB (UserB)
Host github.com-UserB
    HostName github.com
    User UserB
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github.projectb
```

for projectA in .git/config i have the same config of ServerA (right rep)
for projectB in .git/config i have the same config of ServerB (right rep)

Can i use Two different User in the Same Server With different Account and Different SSH ?

Thanks

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have much to do with its title ("Repository not found Git"). Rename?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, then yes, you can have multiple SSH keys and logon to different Github account from the same local account. Make sure you copy both the private and the public keys to ~/.ssh, i.e. both id_rsa.A and id_rsa.A.pub.

Comment: Thanks for reply. in Local Server i have Repositoru Not Found if I want to update my projectB... How can i "choose" different ssh or user?

Answer (score 1):

In my `.git/config` i have to change

```
url = git@github.com:UserB/ProjectB.git
```

to

```
url = git@github.com-UserB:UserB/ProjectB.git
```

Where UserB is in `/root/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com-UserB
```

http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2013/06/22/github-multiple-ssh-keys.html